# Imprimir sub-arboles

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

En el siguiente algoritmo esta el método de ordenamiento heap sort el cual ordena en forma de montículo binario pero quiero imprimir en forma de ternas todos los sub árboles del montículo binario, es decir [Raíz, derecho, izquierdo]. Saben alguna manera para hacer esto posible, adjunto el código donde se da el ordenamiento con el método Heap Sort. Me harian un gran favor, gracias.

```
import math 
def hIzq(i):
    return 2*i

def hDer(i):
    return 2*i+1

def intercambia(A,x,y):
    tmp=A[x]
    A[x]=A[y]
    A[y]=tmp

def maxHeapify (A, i, tamanoHeap):
    L=hIzq(i)
    R=hDer(i)
    if(L<=tamanoHeap and A[L]>A[i]):
        posMax=L
    else:
        posMax=i
    if (R<=tamanoHeap and A[R]>A[posMax]):
        posMax=R
    if (posMax != i):
        intercambia(A, i, posMax)
        maxHeapify (A, posMax, tamanoHeap)

def construirHeapMaxIni (A, tamanoHeap): 
    for i in range (math.ceil((tamanoHeap-1)/2),-1,-1): 
        maxHeapify (A, i, tamanoHeap)

def ordenacionHeapSort (A, tamanoHeap): 
    construirHeapMaxIni (A, tamanoHeap)
    for i in range (len (A)-1,0,-1): 
        intercambia(A,0,i) 
        tamanoHeap=tamanoHeap-1
        maxHeapify (A,0, tamanoHeap)
A = [4,100,68,90,6,9,10]
print(A)
ordenacionHeapSort (A, 6)
print(A)
```

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más específico con la dificultad que enfrentas?

Comment: Claro, quiero que el programa imprima la [raíz, el hijo derecho, el hijo izquierdo] como la composición de un árbol binario.

Comment: Alguna tabla o resultado esperado?